# Domain validation for Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I know, I know... Javascript is a client-side language. Of course, any Javascript required to be read by the browser can be read by the person USING the browser.

But I am building an HTML5 game that runs purely off of Javascript and I am trying to come up with a way to at least omit some necessary variables or functions, and run some validation from a remote location to ensure that the game code is not stolen and ran from another domain.

My initial idea was something along the lines of making the game load some remote content through JSONP or just building the entire game as a web widget, and with any requests, I will do all of the domain validation on my end.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: *"I know, I know... Javascript is a client-side language"* No, it isn't. It's a language. It's used in web browsers (predominantly), on web servers, on non-web servers, at the command line, as a scripting language in non-browser applications...

Comment: problem is, if you're loading remote content, that content load request CAN be intercepted, and then downloaded/cached locally.

Comment: The stolen code can be manipulated to remove the domain requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My vote would be for you to look at anti-CSRF tokens:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19128/csrf-cookie-vs-session-based-tokens
http://www.veracode.com/security/csrf

It's not foolproof, and maybe not what you're really asking for, but it's the closest thing I can think of.

Minify/uglify the source, too.